# inverse functions

Tags: real-analysis

If ${h^{-1}}$$(y)$ is the inverse function to $h$, find the values of $(h^{-1})'(y)$ at the points corresponding to $x=0$, $x=1$, and $x=-1$.

I know that $h(x)=x^3+2x+1$ and $h'(x)=3x^2+1$. Generally, I can find the inverse of a function by writing in terms of $x$ and then switching the $y$ and $x$. But here it seems to be quite difficult. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is actually much the same. Suppose that $h$ is an invertible function, and put $y=h(x)$. Then $x=h^{-1}(y),$ and so differentiating with respect t $x$ and applying the Chain Rule, we have $$1=\frac{d}{dx}[x]=\frac{d}{dx}[h^{-1}(y)]=(h^{-1})'(y)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=(h^{-1})'(y)\cdot h'(x),$$ and so $$(h^{-1})'(y)=\frac1{h'(x)}$$ whenever both sides are defined, where $y=h(x)$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes. I just have to find $(h^{-1})'(y)$ for different values of x's in $h'(x)=3x^2+1$. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have that $$h \circ h^{-1} (x) = x$$ for all $x$ by the definition of the inverse function. Differentiate using the chain rule to find

$$h'(h^{-1}(x)) (h^{-1})'(x)  = 1$$

or rearranging,

$$(h^{-1})' = \frac{1}{h'(h^{-1})}$$

In particular, using your notation that $y = h(x)$, we have

$$\boxed{(h^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{h'(x)}}$$
So for example, if $x = 0$ then $y = h(x) = 1$, so the desired derivative is

$$(h^{-1})'(1) = \frac{1}{h'(h^{-1}(1))} = \frac{1}{h'(0)} = 1$$